# All photos open in pink-black (combination) color in my Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, colors, shotwell, photo, f-spot

When I click on any photo (any image file formats) (stored in my computer) to view, it doesn't open with original colour. The photo opens with combination of pink-black colour. Mostly pink colour is all-over the picture.

The photo is by default open in **GNOME image viewer**

I tried with :

- opening a photo with different photo viewers like :  **F-Spot Photo Viewer** , **Shotwell
  Photo Viewer** etc.
- uninstalled and reinstalled Photo Viewers

All gives me the same result (with pink-black color).

**My System details**:

Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

*GTK version* :

dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0  (command I used)

ii  libgtk-3-0  3.4.2-0ubuntu0.5 GTK+ graphical user interface library

ii  libgtk2.0-0 2.24.10-0ubuntu6 GTK+ graphical user interface library

Please help me solve this issue.

Please let me know if I can provide more information.
Thanks.

Comment: What imageformat do the photos have? I have the same problem with RAW fileformat. Also for comparing i have an AMD graphics card with 13.12 driver (Problem was before with 13.8 to 13.11). Perhaps that way we can figure out, where the problem comes from.

Comment: image file formats :  JPG, JPEG, PNG

Comment: @rechengehirn This is solved now. I posted an answer how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **solved** now.

When I looked at **Update Manager window** which correctly reads :

*Software updates correct errors, eliminate security vulnerabilities and provide new features.*

I've updated software available from **Update Manager** and that fixed my issue with photos.

Now photos look good with any viewer **F-Spot Photo Viewer** , **Shotwell Photo Viewer** etc.